# Huge number of html files are shown in changes when ng-test --code-coverage is run

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am facing a issue where i run ng test --code-coverage then 60-70 html files are generated.So, when i take a pull from other branch it shows code conflict in those files even though i havent chnaged anything.
All the html file are from coverage folder. I have added a screenshot below-
[image]

Comment: In your `.gitignore` file add a `coverage` entry to tell git to ignore all files that are generated in the `coverage` folder.

Comment: @AliF50 i did try that but still all the files are getting generated.

Comment: After adding it, delete the coverage folder locally, rerun the tests, there should be a coverage folder still with the files but it shouldn't be bookkept by git.